# Отрисовка таблицы в текстовом файле

Tags: c, файлы, ascii

Есть небольшой текстовый файл с данными, для лучшего восприятия информации хочу сделать таблицу(в которой эти данные и будут). Как нарисовать таблицу с помощью ASCII символов в процессе заполнения файла я знаю, но как это сделать уже с готовым файлом?Как предусмотреть разное количество символов в каждом столбце?

```
2021-04-21 07:56:04 recipe1 Operator1   23  45  32  56  6.3 55.0    33  9.3 22  56  76  259.6   
2021-04-21 07:56:04 recipe1 Operator1   23  45  32  56  6.3 55.0    33  9.3 22  56  76  259.6
```

Comment: лучше сделайте файл .csv и открывайте его в Excel. Так ИМХО будет лучше для юзера

Comment: *Как нарисовать таблицу с помощью ASCII символов в процессе заполнения файла я знаю, но как это сделать уже с готовым файлом?* Прочитать, распарсить, и записать в новый файл - но уже с табличной разметкой.

Comment: @Akina, каким образом тогда узнать где заканчивается колонка?наличие пробела не гарантирует что это конец колонки.

Comment: А на этот вопрос ВЫ должны ответить. Сформулировать чёткий признак границ полей (например - ни одна из строк файла в данной позиции строки не содержит непробельного символа), и реализовать его распознавание парсером данных.

Answer (score 0):

если колонки выровнены по ширине, то рисовать только в тех столбцах в которых есть пробелы в каждой строке.